# Proof explanation of baby Rudin theorem 5.12

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble understanding the proof for the intermediate value theorem for derivatives. Here is the thereom from Rudin:

> Suppose $f$ is a real differentiable function on $[a,b]$ and suppose $f'(x) < \lambda < f'(b)$. Then there is a point $x \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(x) = \lambda$.

**Proof:** Put $g(t) =f(t) - \lambda t$. Then $g'(a) < 0$, so that $g(t_1) < g(a)$ for some
$t_1 \in (a, b)$, and $g'(b) > 0$, so that $g(t_2) < g(b)$ for some $t_2 \in (a, b)$. Hence $g$ attains its minimum on $[a, b]$ (Theorem 4.16) at some point $x$ such that $a < x < b$. By Theorem 5.8, $g'(x) = 0$. Hence $f '(x) = \lambda$.

I don't understand how $g'(a) < 0$ implies $g(t_1) < g(a)$ for some
$t_1 \in (a, b)$. Same for $t_2$. Any help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$ \lim_{x\to a} \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} = g'(a) < 0 $$
implies that 
$$ \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a} < 0 $$
for $x>a$ sufficiently close to $a$.

Comment: That's wonderful! Now, how do those two facts I asked about imply that $g$ attains a minimum?

Comment: Well, being continuous, $g$ surely attains its minimum (and maximum) on the compact set $[a,b]$. The point of this argument is to show that the minimum is not attained at one of the endpoints.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Then, what specifically about the function $g$ makes it so that it does not attain its minimum at the end points? What would motivate coming up with such a function?

Comment: The inequalities $g(t_1) < g(a)$ and $g(t_2) < g(b)$ are strict.